# Ruby on Rails Private Methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, private-methods

If I'm writing a private method, does rails think that every method under the word `private` is going to be private? or is it supposed to be only private for the first method?

```
  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
```

does that mean `signed_in_user` and `correct_user` is private? or just `signed_in_user`? Does that mean whenever I need to write private methods, it should be at the end of my file now?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, each method after the `private` keyword will be private. If you want to change back to defining non-private methods, you can use a different keyword, like `public` or `protected`.

See [Where to place private methods in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724221/where-to-place-private-methods-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

Yes all the methods under `private` are private. Usually you will, indeed, find those methods at the bottom of your file.

But you can "stop" this by writing another keyword like `protected` and then all the methods following would be protected.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can even define your access control in this way too, listing your methods as arguments to the access control functions (public, protected, private):

```
class SomeClass
    def method1
        ...
    end

    def method2
        ...
    end

    def method3
        ...
    end
    # ... more methods def

    public    :method1, method4
    protected :method3
    private   :method2
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have written, Every method that follows the private keyword immediately is private in Ruby. This is plain Ruby syntax and has nothing to do with rails.

```
private
  .....
def pvt_meth_1
  .....
end

def pvt_meth_2
  .....
end

public

def pub_meth_1
  ......
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It works the same way as c++ private, public tags, so yes both of them will be private